# Read until EOF with gzread and inflate float values

Tags: c++, hex, zlib, tiff, inflate

So I have this TIFF, with compression 32946, which is COMPRESSION_DEFLATE.

I am reading it by hand and got all the TIFF hex values using hexdump.

I now have a value, data3.txt, which contains all hex values from the hexdump.
[Here](https://docs.google.com/document/d/158IK-pKs3ZJsNgezcpNSgGlb8lcuMV7L1pKP-qgI5_k/edit?usp=sharing)  it is pasted into docs:

This is my zlib code so far.

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    gzFile inFileZ = gzopen("data4.txt", "rb");
    unsigned char unzipBuffer[4];
    gzread(inFileZ, unzipBuffer, 4);
    std::cout<<std::hex<<unzipBuffer<<std::endl;
    z_stream stream;
    stream.next_in = unzipBuffer;
    inflate(&stream, 1);
    float *f = (float *) unzipBuffer; 
    printf("%f\n", f);
    gzread(inFileZ, unzipBuffer, 4);
    std::cout<<std::hex<<unzipBuffer<<std::endl;
    stream.next_in = unzipBuffer;
    inflate(&stream, 1);
    f = (float *) unzipBuffer; 
    printf("%f\n", f);
    gzclose(inFileZ);
}
```

and I keep getting first the proper hex value, then 0.0000.What am I doing incorrectly?

Also, without copy-pasting code like I did above, how can I continuously read using gzread till the end of the file?

Comment: The shown code appears to initialize only the `next_in` member of `z_stream`. `z_stream` is a C-style structure, and needs to be fully initialized, as documented. Furthermore, the entire usage of `z_stream` is completely unnecessary. Only `gzread()` is sufficient to uncompress the compressed stream.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik so uncompressing is the same as inflating??

Answer (score 0):

gzopen returns a pointer to a gzfile. inFileZ should be a pointer change the first line to : `gzFile *inFileZ = gzopen("data4.txt", "rb");`
You can read your whole file whith :

```
while(!gzeof(inFileZ){   
 //Your code 
}
```

Make sure zlib.h is included

Comment: What do you mean ?